# How can I escape an HTML tag without using code blocks?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting, character-escaping, html-entities

In a question on [Meta Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/), I want to quote [a comment by SteveFest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/better-hex-color-codes-for-your-internet/123404#comment302916_123404) which displays an HTML tag as a literal set of characters.

[image: Comment with brackets]

I can't find a way to include `<s>not</s>` without surrounding it with code blocks.

- `<s>not</s>` → <s>not</s>
- `<s> not </s>` →  <s>not</s>
- `\<s>not\</s>` → \<s>not\</s>
- `\<s\>not\</s\>` → \not\
- `/<s>not/</s>` → /<s>not/</s>
- `/<s/>not/</s/>` → /not/
- `<code><s>not</s></code>` → `not`
- `< s >not< /s >` → < s >not< /s >

How can I display an HTML tag in a question without enclosing it inside a code block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't render HTML in comments, so you can just type the characters and they appear like that. In posts, anything that looks like invalid, non-allowed HTML gets removed. Instead, you need to escape the characters using HTML entities:

```
&lt;s>not&lt;/s>
```

> <s>not</s>